VS 2022 fails when solution is on Google Drive
VS Community 2022 17.10.3, a tiny console project (One file console app and one DLL with just an empty class skeleton). The project worked.
Now, I use Google Drive as my working drive. All of my documents are stored there, and I feel safe that even if my local drive fails, my files are still on the cloud. So, using "Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/Project Locations," I moved the project location to "drive" K, the drive created by Google Drive.
The build fails with an exception in CreateAppHost: "System.IO.IOException: The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open."
I returned the location to %HomePath%\source\repos, and it's working again!

"I feel safe that even if my local drive fails, my files are still on the cloud" - except that Google Drive, OneDrive, Dropbox etc don't work great for source code. If you want to back your code up, it'd probably be best to obtain specialized software for that. Generally these days, that means using Git and some sort of hosting provider for Git repos, such as GitHub, GitLab, Azure DevOps, etc.

I agree that version control is a must.
